# Advertised package not installed on the client in SCCM 2007

Tags: .net, sccm-2007

I am not sure if this forum is the right place to ask SCCM queries. I have created a tiny environment with one Domain Controller which has SCCM 2007 site server installed. There is one client Vista machine which is connected to it on the same domain. The SCCM client has also been installed on that machine. The problem is, I have created a package to install WinRar and now trying to distribute it to the client. It just does not work, not sure which log file to check for such scenario. In my All Systems collection, I see the client machine, but has the Client flag as "No".

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been out for a while, but I thought I'd put in a response in case you're tracking (or someone else is experiencing the same problem).

I think the prinicipal issue here is that your SCCM client is not talking with the site server.  There are a few reasons this could be happening.  First, make sure your firewall settings for both the client and server are correct http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb694088.aspx.  Yeah, I know, but it still happens in my office even after all these years ;).  Second, if you are using native mode, make sure everything is set up correctly in PKI.  This can particularly troublesome if you have multiple machine certificates.  This is probably where I see the most issues.  If you are using native mode and it appears to be the issue, send a reply and I can gove over some troubleshooting steps for that as well.  Finally, ensure that the client is configured correctly.  It is possible for the client to be depolyed but in a dormant state (i.e. not assigned to a site server).  The easist way to link the two up is to do a client push from SCCM, forcing an install.  This automatically sets the correct params for the client.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Oh, and this type of question will probably get better responses on serverfault.